# SmartNav tracking keeps switching between "tracking" and "no data"

Tags: windows-7, smartnav

From time to time, SmartNav tracking keeps switching between "tracking" and "no data". Restarting SmartNav application doesn't help, but rebooting the computer or re-connecting the SmartNav device solves the issue.

1. What cause the issue to appear?
2. How to fix it without rebooting the computer or re-connecting the SmartNav device?

[image]

I use a SmartNav 4 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.